# online users list using servletContextListener

Tags: jsp, servlet-3.0

i am new to web programming here i don't have idea about listing all online users in my servlet using servlet Context Listener but i am stuck with implement this. Has anyone have answer please let me know with some example. thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: i have tried to login module only here i want store the user list into Application context but still not get an idea ... i am doing in jsp - servlet

Answer (score 0):

I will just give you the general path, because a detailed answer with code would be too long.

You should :

- keep a hash of currently logged in users (sessionid : user) in a servlet context attribute - be sure to initialize it to an empty hash in a ServletContextListener (contextInitialized event)
- add entries to it in the module that processes login
- remove entries from it a HttpSessionListener (sessionDestroyed event)

Just glue that together in your application and it should do it ...

Comment: Client clients=new Client(strUser.toLowerCase());
      System.out.println("online strUser:"+clients.getUserName());
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Map<String, List<Client>> channelsClientsMap = (Map<String, List<Client>>) appScope.getAttribute(CLIENTS);
      List<Client> onlineClients=new ArrayList<Client>();
      onlineClients.add(clients);    this is correct way add in hash?

Comment: @selvaprasath : You can use a list, but I advise you to use a hash indexed with `sessionId` in case same user logs in different sessions. And I fixed a problem in my answer : entries should only be added after a successful login. So it would be something like `Map<String, List<Client>> onlineClients = (Map<String, Client>) context.getAttribute(CLIENTS); onlineClients.put(getSession().getId(), client);` after a successful login.

Comment: thanks serge-ballesta i got the list of users as u said

Comment: hi friend i gotta an idea to use old solution with peer to peer chat application. Is it possible to implement this then give some way